# Advertisement programs that allow "clickjacking" (earning advertisement revenues by popups generated by clicks on the website)?

Tags: google-adsense, advertising

Whether clickjacking is an ethically responsible way of earning advertisement revenues is a subjective discussion and should not be discussed here.

However, it appears that quite a lot of popular sites generate "popups" when you click either of their links or buttons. An example is the Party Poker advertisement (I am sure many of you will have seen this one).

I wonder though, what kind of advertisement companies allow such techniques? Surely Google Adsense does not? But which do, and are they reliable partners?

Update: an example of an organization using clickjacking to earn advertisement revenues is The Pirate Bay. When clicking on a torrent link, advertisements of Party Poker will popup.

Comment: To clarify, you are looking for help figuring out which companies will allow you to trick users into clicking on ads so you can "earn" advertising revenue and you want to know which companies are "reliable" - as in, which companies will let you trick your users but won't try to trick you?

Comment: @danlefree, that is a very pessimistic view but mostly correct. Such advertisement methods are very common nowadays.

Comment: It looks like someone downvoted this question based on his ethical feelings. If not, please provide constructive criticism.

Comment: Using The Pirate Bay as an example doesn't lend this tactic any credence

Comment: @Tom - I thought my initial comment explained my downvote. Regardless of whether or not *you want* others to consider the ethical ramifications of what you are trying to do, clickjacking is commonly held to be an exploit: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking

Comment: @danlefree, I believe clickjacking there is regarded as trying to scam someone, for example by making users post something when they did not want to. Obviously all this would do is show a popup when the user clicks a normal link. Also please see my comment made to Ewan's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to earn money by scamming people then the ads currently running on the Pirate Bay appear to come from a company called DSNR Media Group. However, unsurprisingly, it seems that they aren't too hot on actually paying publishers. There's a thread about it here http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=879088

I imagine that if you do actually get paid at all then the commissions will be pathetically low so you'll need to generate the level of traffic that the Pirate Bay gets in order to make it worth bothering with. Unfortunately that will probably be difficult as it's unlikely you'll be listed in Google for very long, if at all. Maybe you should look for a more original idea to make money online. You should be thinking of ways to benefit both users and advertisers as that appears to be the best formula for making money from internet ads.

Comment: this is nothing new to me. I should note that at the moment I am merely considering the alternatives and looking for these companies as I want to know how commonly accepted this technique is, even though it is already apparent on numerous popular sites. Anyway, when used for mere advertising, or the generation of a popup when a link is clicked -- I cannot see how you can regard this as scamming. My service is about 6 years young now and quite popular, but adding normal banners would totally destroy the user experience as the visible area is of high important for the service to be proper

Comment: On the other hand, after 6 years I have to look for ways of monetization. After comparing all the possibilities, a popup that appears behind the actual screen (so does not interfere) and only occurs on rare occasions actually seems to be the least annoying possibility. As no such advertisement programs have been mentioned apart from the above one, that is highly questionable, I doubt that I will use the technique though. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use large banner ads that get in the users way. You could look for specific ads that are going to be most useful for them and test out placing them in different areas of the site. You should consider signing up for one of the PPA networks and looking through the available ads to see what will fit. You can then monitor which ads are actually making money. In the end, if users are clicking on ads then making purchases, you've provided them with a service of relevant ads, you've given the advertiser qualified leads and earned the money to keep you site going as well.